# One Compliance Server for multiple anchors?

Tags: compliance

Is it possible to set up just 1 compliance server that can be called upon from multiple bridge servers? Or would you need a seperate compliance for every bridge server connecting to it?

Answer (score 1):

In theory this should be possible, though I have not tested this out. In doing this however you will need to consider the following:

1. The multiple bridge servers should be able to connect to the compliance server internal port securely. You shouldn't make the internal port publicly accessible.
2. The callbacks you provide will need to be able to differentiate the request for the various anchors.
3. The anchors will all list the compliance URL as in their stellar.toml file.

If you do get to test it out, let us know how it goes.